# Display images one by one using Python PIL library

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I intend to show a list of images in a directory one by one using Python PIL(i.e close the previous image window before the next image window opens). Here is my code which doesn't seem to work . It opens images one after the other without closing the previous window.

```
def show_images(directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        path = directory + "/" + filename
        im = Image.open(path)
        im.show()
        im.close()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Can anyone help me with this? I insist on using the PIL library.
Thanks

Comment: if libraries aren't an issue for you, then you may try the 'cv2' library, where you can use cv2.waitKey(0) to sow images in succession.

Comment: PIL calls an external viewer program to display the image. Which one is it using for you? It's likely either `display` or `xv`; are these available on your system and in your PATH?

Comment: PIL's `.show` method is just a convenience function to allow the developer to view images while writing code, it's not intended to be used to display images to the user. If your program needs to control image display you should use a GUI framework. This is easy enough to do in Tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

PIL.show() calls an external program to display the image, after storing it in a temporary file, could be the GNOME image viewer or even the inline matplotlib if you use iPython notebook.

From what I gather from their documentation [PIL](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#image-processing) here, I see that the only way to do this is, to do a `pkill` through a os.system() call or a subprocess call.

So you could change your program to something like this :

```
import os
def show_images(directory):
 for filename in os.listdir(directory):
     path = directory + "/" + filename
     im = Image.open(path)
     im.show()
     os.system('pkill eog') #if you use GNOME Viewer
     im.close()
     time.sleep(5)
```

If you don't have a necessity to use PIL exclusively, you can try switching to other libraries such as matplotlib for showing, as described here [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html), where a simple call such as plot.close() will close the figure, and plot.clear() will clear the figure

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show_images(directory):
 for filename in os.listdir(directory):
     path = directory + "/" + filename
     im = Image.open(path)
     plt.imshow(im)
     plt.show()
     plt.clf() #will make the plot window empty
     im.close()
     time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work , it just starts a new image window without killing the previous one.

Comment: can you try using matplotlib to display the images? will edit and add a new snippet for that now.