# How to read images into a script without using using imageio or scikit image?

Tags: python, image, scipy

I am trying to read a `png` image in python. The `imread` function in `scipy` is being [deprecated](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html#scipy.ndimage.imread) and they recommend using `imageio` library.

However, I am would rather restrict my usage of external libraries to  `scipy`, `numpy` and `matplotlib` libraries. Thus, using `imageio` or `scikit image` is not a good option for me.

Are there any methods in python or `scipy`, `numpy` or `matplotlib` to read images, which are not being deprecated?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

With matplotlib you can use (as shown in the matplotlib [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/users/image_tutorial.html))

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img=mpimg.imread('image_name.png')
```

And plot the image if you want

```
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Note that this is no longer done internally by matplotlib, but delegated to pillow internally ([see the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html)), so you can't avoid the extra dependency. ImageIO does the same internally (unless explicitly told to use a different backend), so - in 2022 - there is almost no difference between this answer, the answer suggesting pillow below, and using ImageIO as suggested in the question. Personally, I prefer ImageIO because it is more flexible than the other options (but I maintain the library, so take that with some salt).

Answer (score 23):

You can also use [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) like this:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("image_path.jpg")
image.show()
```

Answer (score 9):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = plt.imread('images/my_image4.jpg')
plt.imshow(image)
```

*Using 'matplotlib.pyplot.imread' is recommended by warning messages in jupyter.*

Comment: But it works, because:
"If not given, the format is deduced from the filename. If nothing can be deduced, PNG is tried."(https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html)

Answer (score 5):

> If you just want to **read an image in Python** using the specified
>   libraries only, I will go with `matplotlib`

**In matplotlib :**

```
import matplotlib.image
read_img = matplotlib.image.imread('your_image.png')
```

Answer (score 4):

For the better answer, you can use these lines of code.
Here is the example maybe help you :

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('/home/pictures/1.jpg')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

In **`imread()`**  you can pass the directory .so you  can also use `str()`  and `+` to combine dynamic directories and fixed directory like this:

```
path = '/home/pictures/'
for i in range(2) :
    image = cv2.imread(str(path)+'1.jpg')
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

Both are the same.

Comment: if i wanted to create a for loop which opens all the images within the folder 1 by 1 how would i do that using the above? Thanks

Comment: @OscarDolloway  I hope [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357641/display-images-one-by-one-using-python-pil-library) help you.

Comment: it says `NameError: name 'cv2' is not defined`.  is this answer missing an `import`?

Comment: @john-henckel Yes. Sure. You need to install ```OpenCV-Python``` first with this command: ```pip3 install opencv-python``` and then ```import cv2```. 
For exact answer ```cv2``` is the interface of ```opencv``` so you need to install it first. For reading more this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417108/what-is-different-between-all-these-opencv-python-interfaces) is good.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/image_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20image#module-matplotlib.image.imread):

> Matplotlib can only read PNGs natively. Further image formats are supported via the optional dependency on Pillow.

So in case of `PNG` we may use `plt.imread()`. In other cases it's probably better to use `Pillow` directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use cv2 like this

```py
import cv2

image= cv2.imread('image page')

cv2.imshow('image', image)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I read all answers but I think one of the best method is using [openCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) library.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('your_image.png',0)
```

and for displaying the image, use the following code :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way**

from IPython.display import Image

Image(filename ="Covid.jpg" size )