# Displaying a Single Image to Screen From Multidimensional Numpy Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, matplotlib

I am working with some open source code that outputs an array of 64 images. The images are stored in a variable that is a multidimensional Numpy array.

```
type(images)
>> numpy.ndarray
len(images)
>> 64
type(images[3])
>> numpy.ndarray
len(images[3])
>> 64
images.shape
>> (64, 64, 64, 3)
images[0].shape
>> (64, 64, 3)
```

What I would like to be able to do is to select the image at a particular index and display that image to the screen (in this case Jupyter Notebook)

From this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357641/display-images-one-by-one-using-python-pil-library), I know that part of the solution will be code in the following format:

```
     plt.imshow(<image>)
     plt.show()
```

However, I'm new two working with images in the multidimensional array format, so I'm not understanding how to properly slice the array in order to access a single image at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
def showImage(images, imageIndex):
    plt.imshow( images[imageIndex])
    plt.show()

showImage(images,0) #shows the first image
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks much.